# For_Loop class is not working as expected on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

My For loop is not working and my print statement (i) is showing error in eclipse

Following is the code.

```
public class For_Loop {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++);
    System.out.println(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: remove the semicolon from for loop end of line and add brackets to mark the block of functions you are looping over.

Comment: Replace the semicolon after the for loop with a bracket {

Comment: @hasnae actually, it is not a syntax error, but a logic error...

Comment: Thanks. Its working now

Comment: just remove ; at the end of for line, no need to open bracket if the loop block is only one line

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `;` at end of for

```
public class For_Loop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Please remove the semicolon from for loop.

```
public class For_Loop {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
                System.out.println(i);

        }
    }
```